# VS2010 Custom Settings Class Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom settings class (inheriting from ApplicationSettingsBase) and I wish to replicate the functionality of showing a control for the editing of that class. How do I do this, as I can't find anywhere that will show me?

I have spent a long time searching but I apologise if the solution is already out there.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I want to edit my custom settings at run-time is use a PropertyGrid with the `SelectedObject` property set to the name of my class:

```
public class frmOptions
{
    CustomSettings MySettings = new CustomSettings();

    private frmOptions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = MySettings;
    }
}
```